# Having trouble understanding PostgresSQL relationships between tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, relationship

I have built a SQL database before, but for some reason I am having trouble visualizing how to properly set up this database.

1. Agencies have Agents ( An agent can only be part of 1 agency at a time, but because bonds may last years, and the agent may switch Agencies, I am not sure how to handle this ).
2. Agents are part of Bonds (as a reference)
3. Defendants have Bonds ( They can be added to the database without a bond at first, but from that defendant's page/route, the user will be able to "create a bond", which will add the bond to the database )
4. Defendants MAY ( might ) have Dependents ( people who pay off their bonds ). Thus, a Bond will have 1 Defendant ( required ), and can have 1 dependent ( but not required ).
5. Defendants can have multiple Dependents at any given time, but each has to be a part of their own bond.

On the front end of the application, I want everything to be linked. When I create a defendant > create a dependent > create a bond ( and allow the user to choose a list of ONLY the dependents for the specific defendant ) , etc, I want the rest of the application to be updated ( i.e the Bonds page will now show a new bond in the list, with all the data ).

Here is a picture of my current file structure. I decided to start off with this and ask my question now before moving onto the other tables. I think I am on the right track, but take a look. I haven't figured out how to add FK in pgadmin, but I will do that once I figure out how to do this the right way.

[image]

As you can see, I created a table called "defdeprelations", which is meant to act as a table to show what dependents belong to which defendants, and on which bond. On the front end, I have a tab on the Defendants page called "dependents" which shows a table with all of that Defendant's Dependents, and on which bond...However, where I am confused is how this will work with multiple bonds.

Is there a way to create an array of bond_ids , or is there a better way of going about this? Thank you in advance for taking the time to read.

Comment: Did you try drawing an ER diagram for your proposed database tables? From the description in your question, I see five tables as follows: AGENCIES, AGENTS, BONDS, DEFENDANTS, DEPENDENTS. Do you concur?

Comment: If I understood your last question correctly, you want an array of integers in the `bond_id` column of the `defdeprelations` table.

You can define this column as type array and then update/access the array as needed using postgresql's array functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html

Comment: You didn't explain how agents relate to anything, but if they can only work for one agency, you could map it as agent_agency table with a start_date and end_date (which is null for current employmnet) - no agent may have two null end dates (trigger). Also sounds to me like defendants have bonds and bonds have dependents. A bond has a defendant_id saying who the bond belongs to, and a dependent may have a bond id, or if a dependent will have multiple bonds, a dependent_bond table to map the bonds to the dependents

Comment: @Ferdinand55 thanks this helps a lot